# When does a objective-c call to a javascript function gets called/executed and when not?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, google-maps-api-3

what is the dependence on if the javascript gets called or Executed? I have two functions which both get called the same way, to be precise:

```
[self.mapView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"setMarkerAtPosition(%f,%f)",
                                           latlong.latitude, latlong.longitude]];
```

and

```
[self.mapView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"test()"];
```

but `calculateRoute()` gets executed while `test()` is not. How come?

```
function setMarkerAtPosition(lat, long){
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: position, 
                                              map: map, 
                                            title:"Hello World!", 
                                         animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP});
    var content = "Ich bin eine normale Infobox";
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                              infowindow.setContent(content);
                              infowindow.open(map,marker); 
                              reportClickedMarker();
                              });
```

}

```
function test(){
    alert(currentPosition.latitude + ', ' + currentPosition.longitude);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: You'll probably need to show the code that is calling those functions

Comment: it is the same other than the function name

Comment: Ok, you're not getting me. You need to include the code that is calling those functions; otherwise, the answer to your question is "Your guess is as good as mine". Don't include it as a comment either, please actually **edit** your question with the rest of the code involved here. Thank you ;)

Comment: I did... you must read more carefully ;-) it's in the text (2nd line) and a one-liner..

Comment: jmort253 may be referring to the objective-c code?

Comment: it is in the second line of the post !? The first sentence says "the code gets called from [CODE HERE]..." 
[self.mapView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"functionName()"]; edited the first post to make it extremely clear... ;-)

Comment: I don't see "functionName" included here anywhere. I was hoping you'd post the actual code and not a fake example. If I'm missing something, I'm sorry, but it looks to me like the actual code that calls calculateRoute and test is not included. For instance, how do we know that function is actually being called? Maybe you have a conditional block causing your code to not even be fired? Maybe there's something else causing it to not be fired that we can't see in your obj-c? Have you tried replacing calculateRoute with test, so that the same part of your code is calling the other function?

Comment: Again, to be clear `[self.mapView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"functionName()"];` is not your actual code, if you're using this, then that explains why it's not working because `functionName` is not a function that you allegedly have included in your JavaScript. Show actual code.

Comment: i added the actual code sir :-) I'm sorry for not posting it in the first plcae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling `calculateRoute()` anywhere. **`test()`** is getting called because you are calling it with:

```
[self.mapView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"test()"];
```

Comment: sorry i've been coding for nearly 10 hours straight, I copied the wrong part, sorry! fixed it